# how to handle events and initiating server request in sencha?

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, extjs

i am working on an application using sencha where i have a login screen with two buttons exit and submit. Here i am struggling for handling the events. Also i have two handlers for two buttons. But how can i get the text from the text fields ? how can i initiate a server request. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
Ext.setup({
    icon: 'icon.png',
    tabletStartupScreen: 'tablet_startup.png',
    phoneStartupScreen: 'phone_startup.png',
    glossOnIcon: false,

    onReady: function() {

        var form;

        var formBase = {
            scroll : 'vertical',            
            standardSubmit : false,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    title: 'Login Screen',
                    instructions: 'Enter agent number and password to login.',
                    defaults: {
                        required: true,
                        labelAlign: 'left',
                        labelWidth: '45%'
                    },
                    items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name : 'username',
                        label: 'Agent Number',
                        useClearIcon: true
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                        name : 'password',
                        label: 'Password',
                        useClearIcon: false
                    }]
                }],
            listeners : {
                submit : function(form, result){
                    console.log('success', Ext.toArray(arguments));
                },
                exception : function(form, result){
                    console.log('failure', result);
                }
            },

            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    dock: 'bottom',
                    items: [
                        {
                            text: 'Login',
                            ui: 'confirm',
                            handler: function() {
                                  alert('Login please wait..');
                            } 
                        }, 
                        {
                            text: 'Exit',
                            ui: 'exit',
                            handler: function() {
                                  alert('Are you sure ?');                               
                            } 
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };

        if (Ext.is.Phone) {
            formBase.fullscreen = true;
        } else {
            Ext.apply(formBase, {
                autoRender: true,
                floating: true,
                modal: true,
                centered: true,
                hideOnMaskTap: false,
                height: 385,
                width: 480
            });
        }

        form = new Ext.form.FormPanel(formBase);
        form.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use `Ext.Msg.alert` instead `alert`. Also for the login please wait alert try using `from.setLoading(true)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values from the textfield use `form.getValues();`. To make a request use:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
     url: 'ajax_demo/sample.json',
    method: 'GET',
    params:{
          username:usernameValue, 
          password:passValue},
    success: function(response, opts) {
        var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        console.dir(obj);
    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {
        console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
    }});
```

**Update**

First change the name of the fields to `user` and `pass` then put the following code instead `alert('Login please wait..');`

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: '140.45.45.20:9010/TService/Sms/Services',
  params: form.getValues(),
  method: 'GET',
  success: function(response, opts) {
    var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
    console.dir(obj);
    //The request was successful - see the response in the response object
 },
 failure: function(response, opts) {
    console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
}});
```

Comment: Hi llija, my doubt might be little stupid. please bare with me. I have an base url = "http://140.45.45.20:9010/TService/Sms/Services" in this i want to include ?user="username" and ?pass="password" paras to GET request. I basically didnt understand much of your code as i am a very beginner to Extjs. please guide me.

Comment: i am still struggling with this. Here the request fails as we are sending using POST. My web service is able to respond GET request. is it possible?

Comment: It should send GET by default. Add this property to the request `method:'GET'` (see updated code above).